# Tableau server installation issue

Tags: tableau-api

After installation tableau server i'm not redirected to **Create Admin User** page, instead i'm redirected to page for Sign In, with **Sign in failed** error.
I'm trying to Sign in with my active directory user but still i'm getting sign in failed error.

i set username like this:
Domain\user

would you please someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i didn't have unrestricted admin privilege access on server.